# What is the easiest way to migrate machine and data from one AWS account to another

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have simple server with EBS on one amazon account. I want it to migrate to other AWS account. What is the easiest way to do this? Is there are some tutorial on this topic?

Comment: I've answered this question on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/a/322674/30542

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't. That's the short answer. But what you can do is make an AMI based off that server and share it with the other account.